# Correct use of get_the_terms()

Tags: terms

I need to print all terms associated to a custom post type post.
In the post template I wrote that code:

```
<?php foreach (get_the_terms(the_ID(), 'taxonomy') as $cat) : ?>
     <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The loop works correctly, but before the list also the id was printed. Like:

```
37
taxonomy01
taxonomy02
taxonomy03
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`the_ID()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) print the post ID. You need to use the [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/) which return the post ID.

Example:

```
foreach (get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy') as $cat) {
   echo $cat->name;
}
```

Always remember the naming convention of WordPress for template tags. `the` which mean to print `get` which mean to return in most of the cases.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize the difference.

Comment: *Always remember the naming convention of WordPress for template tags. `the` which mean to print `get` which mean to return* WordPress does not always follow these. Template tags does not always use the `the` and `get` prefixes

Comment: I was thinking about that my statement is not 100% true. Edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can declare a variable.

```
$taxonomy = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy' );

foreach ( $taxonomy as $tax ) {
   echo esc_html( $tax->name ); 
}
```